# How can I loop only the page records from the selected one to the latest?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav, dynamics-business-central, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I'm trying to loop all records displayed in a page, from the selected one to the end of the rows:

[image]

For example here, as I'm selecting only the 5th row it will loop through 5th and 6th row (as there are no more rows below)

What I've been trying is this:

```
ProdOrderLine := Rec;

REPEAT
UNTIL ProdOrderLine.NEXT = 0;
```

But it will loop through all records in the table which are not even displayed in the page...

How can I loop only the page records from the selected one to the latest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/methods-auto/record/record-copy-method) instead of assignment. Assignment only copies values of there field from one instance of record-variable to another, it died not copy filters or keys (sort order).

Alas, I have to mention that this is uncommon scenario to handle records like this in BC. General best practice approach would be to ask user to select all the records he or she needs with the shift+click, ctrl+click or by dragging the mouse. In that case you will use [SetSelectionFiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/methods-auto/page/page-setselectionfilter-method) to instantly grab ask the selected records.

This is how it works across the system and this how user should be taught to work. It is a bad idea to add a way to interact with record that only works in one page in the whole system even if users are asking for it bursting into tears. They probably just had this type of interaction in some other system they worked with before. I know this is a tough fight but it worth it. It is for the sake of stability (less coding = less bugs) and predictability (a certain way of interaction works across all the pages) of the system.